# C# WPF when installing my application on other machines it doesn' work like i designed

Tags: c#, wpf, installation, project

i programmed an application using C# WPF now it works fine on my machine when i debug and also when installing but it doesn't work like it supposed to work on some other machines , some of them accepted my exe file and worked just like i designed and some of them made the textboxes and labels not aligned probably and the text of the buttons also changed a little not like as i designed and they look horrible but the logic and inside programming works fine but the design is just so horrible for the user and not like i designed
P.S : this is from the design perspective , NO ERRORS!

Comment: There is, unfortunately, no question in your question. There's some good guidance on how to ask a *good* question here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: my question is how to make it probably works over all machines ! no need to be a bot when you read something

Comment: your question can really be better... you could have added screenshots, given more info about what you've used, versions, which machines, and so on ...

Comment: it tells me i can't post any pictures because of a rank or something , how i can edit my question ?

Comment: Can you show us screenshots of the application on different machines? Also, could you list the versions of Windows and the DPI settings of the machines you are deploying to?

Comment: @MoeKhali If you can't post screenshots, upload them to imgur and paste a link into your post. Someone with enough rep will edit them into the question. Also, show your layout XAML.

Answer (score -1):

i'm not sure what you guys are so confused about his question.... if you don't know the answer just say u don't lol

anyways the first thing that comes in my mind is maybe the control's borders change and that changes the position of other controls?
try to set ur controls width and height on auto and see if that helps + u can try play with ur control's margin a little.

Comment: they came here to get some reps , not to help people , thanks for the answer

Answer (score -1):

This is a scenario when usinf RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions really shine. I would suggest doing this since you are having issues with the UI not displaying properly on all deployed machines.